# Why can't get right logical query for the if statement in mysql procedure?

Tags: mysql, procedure

Query all data when year is 18:

```
SELECT * from tb where year=18 //
+----+------+------+------+
| id | name | year | num  |
+----+------+------+------+
|  2 | a    |   18 |  400 |
|  4 | b    |   18 |  200 |
|  6 | c    |   18 |  100 |
+----+------+------+------+
```

Now i wrote a mysql procedure:

```
create procedure show_data(in type char,myear int)
begin
if type = "all" then 
    SELECT * from tb where year=myear;
elseif type != "all" then
    SELECT * from tb where name=type and year=myear;
end if;
end //
```

The logic in procedure `show_data` is clear:when the input argument `type` is all ,and myear is `18`,the query is just `SELECT * from tb where year=18` according to the procedure.

What i got with `call show_data("all",18)` is as below:

```
call show_data("all",18)//
+----+------+------+------+
| id | name | year | num  |
+----+------+------+------+
|  2 | a    |   18 |  400 |
+----+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

show warnings//
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                   |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'type' at row 1 |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: give a IN value for char like `char(3)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring variable `type` as `char`. This only allows a single character. Hence the error that you are getting when you try to assign a string that contains three characters (`'all'`).

Consider [this example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3bbDgvaY9GxAuv4GWxrJ5i/0):

```
delimiter //
create procedure debug_char(in type char, myear int)
begin
    select type;
end 
//

call debug_char('abc', 1);
```

Yields:

```
Error: ER_DATA_TOO_LONG: Data too long for column 'type' at row 1
```

You would need to change the datatype to `char(3)` so the value can fit in it (you actually want the same max char length as in column `name` if that is more than 3).

Note: your code could be simplified by moving the logic to the query itself instead of using `if`, as follows:

```
delimiter //
create procedure debug_char(in type char(3), myear int)
begin
    select * from tb where (name = type or type = 'all') and year = myear;
end
//
```